# Is there a way to get flexible **Width** and resizing items (not moveable) using Masonry or Cards (Bootstrap) or something else?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

Is there a way to get flexible **Width** and resizing items (not moveable) using Masonry or Cards (Bootstrap) or something else?

Does Bootstrap 4 Cards has flexible Width?
I'm using Masonry and have created a design I like. @ https://codepen.io/stephyswe/pen/ZKZaRm . But when I try to re-size the browser it moves around the items. I rather have it resize the items so I can still have the same layout. 
I also looked into Bootstrap 4 - Cards - and couldn't find anything that makes me created this kind of Layout shown below. Cards however does provide me with flexible Width. 
At the moment, I'm stuck between Masonry, that gives me flexible width but not responsive items. And Bootstraps - Card - which allows resizable items, but doesn't provide the flexible width.

Layout and Code from Codepen @ Using Masonry.
https://snag.gy/b4iuSc.jpg

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width5 grid-item--height4">1</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height4">2</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4 grid-item--height2">3</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3">4</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3 grid-item--height2">5</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width4">6</div>
</div>
```